# Order Isomorphism of Cartesian Products

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've got the following problem to solve: 
Are  $N\times R$ and $R \times R$ with lexicographical order isomorphic?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I guess $N$ and $R$ are the sets of natural and real numbers, respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: look at all Dedekind cuts, i.e. all divisions of the set $X$ ($X$ could be $\mathbb N\times\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$) into two nonempty sets $A, B\subseteq X, A\cup B=X$ such that for every $a\in A, b\in B$ we have $a\lt b$.

For some of those Dedekind cuts $(A,B)$ there will be $x\in X$ such that $x\ge a (a\in A)$ and $x\le b (b\in B)$. For some, there won't be such $x$.

What is the cardinality of the set of Dedekind cuts that don't have the corresponding $x$? Also, is this cardinality an invariant of the order isomorphism?

Comment: Could you give me examples of Dedekind cuts with corresponding x? And why is the cardinality of Dedekind cuts important? Sorry for such questions, but I'm new to set theory.

Comment: For example, choose $n\in\mathbb N$, and take $A=\{(m,x)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb R\mid m\lt n\}$ and $B=\{(m,x)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb R\mid m\ge n\}$. There is no element in $\mathbb N\times\mathbb R$ that is exactly "between" $A$ and $B$. Repeat the same construction for $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$. In the first case, you get countably many such Dedekind cuts (are those all such cuts?) and in the second case you get uncountably many.

Comment: (Cont'd) However, you asked me for those cuts having the corresponding element in between: choose the element in between $(m_0, x_0)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb R$ up-front, and take e.g. $A=\{(m,x)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb R\mid (m,x)\lt(m_0, x_0)\}$ and $B=\{(m,x)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb R\mid (m,x)\ge(m_0, x_0)\}$.

Comment: (Cont'd) I also hope, as you say you are new to set theory, that there is a more elementary solution to this; hope someone will come up with such an answer. If there isn't, I am afraid this is quite a hard problem for a beginner.

Comment: Okay. And these orders are not isomorhic, because of different cardinality of Dedekind cuts without corresponding element?

Comment: @m3mir That is right, but I would leave it to you to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0):

Connected components in both spaces are of the form {x}×R.
One space has countably many components, the other uncountably many.
If they were order isomorphic they'd be homeomorphic, which they are not.